Is it possible to use the Cech complex to compute coherent cohomology in practice?
Suppose I have a closed subvariety $V$ of $\mathbb P^n \times \mathbb A^m$ given by explicit equations. Is it possible in practice to compute the coherent cohomology of $V$ with coefficients in a line bundle pulled back from $\mathbb P^n$ using the Cech complex for the open affine cover of $V$ by intersections of $V$ with the products of the standard affine open subsets of $\mathbb P^n$ with $\mathbb A^m$ (similarly to how cohomology of the projective space with coefficients in a line bundle is computed)? If not, how to compute this cohomology?

Yes you can but you would need an "acyclic" cover of $V$, i.e., a cover  of $V$ by affine (Stein) subvarieties of $V$ such that their intersections are also affine (Stein). This reduces the computation to a simplicial cohomology computation which could be challenging . Even when $m=0$ and  $\dim V=1$ this could be tricky.

@LiviuNicolaescu Thank you! Is it okay to take the following cover? If I take the cover of $\mathbb P^n$ by the $n+1$ standard open affine spaces $U_i$, $i=1,..,n+1$, then it has the property that their intersections are also affine varieties. So the cover of $V$ given by the open subsets $V \cap (U_i \times \mathbb A^m)$ of $V$ also has the property that their intersections are affine varieties because their intersections are $V \cap ((\cap_{i \in I} U_i) \times \mathbb A^m)$ which are closed subvarieties of affine varieties hence themselves affine varieties.

@LiviuNicolaescu Do you think using the Cech complex is the best way to approach this problem? Are there other ways? What about using local cohomology like in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55334/cohomology-of-structure-sheaves ? Would this be more or less efficient?

The cohomology of a line bundle  over say curve is sensitive to both the complex structure on the curve and the complex structure on the bundle. Look for example at a curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$. The affine varieties you mention look like lines with points removed, in fact the number of points removed  is exactly the degree of the curve.

@LiviuNicolaescu If we look at a curve in $\mathbb P^2$ of degree $d$ then its genus is $g=(d-1)(d-2)/2$. So if $d \geq 3$ the genus is positive, so I don't think that charts on the curve look like lines with points removed, rather they look like a curve of genus $g$ with $d$ points removed, right?

@Yellow Pig I once asked a question about the correctness of an algorithm that would supply you with a solution to your problem here on MO. It is https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301923/an-algorithm-to-compute-coherent-sheaf-cohomology-in-projective-space-over-a-rin I had tested the algorithm successfully on some examples from Mumfords "Lectures on curves on an algebraic surface" and some other test examples I made up and it should be correct for a field $A$. The question was closed and received no answers and I had no other opportunity to get it corroborated, maybe you want to have a look.

@JürgenBöhm Thank you very much! Is the projective space $\mathbb P^n_A$ in your algorithm equal to the product $\mathbb P^n \times \mathbb A^m$ for some ring $A$? (Namely one should probably take $A=k[y_1,...,y_m]$)

@Yellow Pig Yes, for $\mathbb{A}^m$ you have to take $A=k[y_1,\ldots,y_m]$. What do you think about the correctness of my argument in the article? I nowhere found the idea to take $H^n(X-)$ as the basic right-exact functor and $H^{n-i}(X,-)$ as its $i$-th satellite functor but it appeared sound to me. It would be great to have a second (and third..) opinion on this! (That $H^n(X,-)$ is right exact follows by the way from the fact that $\mathbb{P}^n_A$ can be covered by $n+1$-affines and Cech-cohomology).

@Yellow Pig I just tested the algorithm with an older Macaulay2 and also the newest version in the web interface. Unfortunately it could not compute correct results for even very simple examples where I had thought it could. I think the abstract algorithm as stated in the link is still correct, but it might be impossible to implement it in Macaulay2 - at least not in the way I did in the example code there. The example code should work for A a field, say A=QQ, but a polynomial ring, e.g. A = QQ[a], seems to cause errors the root of which I could not pinpoint.

@Yellow Pig The problem seems to be that for A=QQ[a] and S=A[x_0..x_4] and ma = matrix {{(a-1)*x_0, (a-1)*x_1,(a-1)*x_2,(a-1)*x_3,(a-1)*x_4}} and mo1 = coker ma on the one hand prune(mo1) is nonzero but prune truncate(d, mo1) is zero for d greater than zero.

@Yellow Pig I chased the errors further and tried to circumvent them - it was partly successful, some tests which blatantly failed, now go (with new code) through correctly. It was necessary to write a custom 'truncate' function, as the inbuilt truncate seems to work wrong. Also the output chain complex had to be lifted to a new ring isomorphic to A. If you are still interested, you can leave a comment here.

@JürgenBöhm Thank you very much! Your algorithm is very interesting and we may use it in our project, I will let you know if we end up using it.

@JürgenBöhm I think what I need is cohomology of a sheaf on $\mathbb P^n_A$ as a module over $A$, does your method compute this? Thanks!

@Yellow Pig Yes, exactly, this is what the algorithm computes. You apply $H^n(X,-)$ to a sequence of $S$-modules and get a sequence of $A$-modules. If you want to try it out with Macaulay2 yourself: The code is in test.m2 on http://www.aviduratas.de/compalg.html (search for test.m2 on the page). (If you enter -999 as the second argument of compCohX everything should work automatically right).

@JürgenBöhm Great, thank you very much, I will try it

@Yellow Pig Just a short note: I removed test.m2 from the page cited above and replaced it with compcoh-2024-08.m2 where I have cleaned the code a bit!
